# Jquery click function not being called

Tags: jquery

This is kind of an off little issue and I am sure I'm missing something really small, but I swear I am going crazy.

I have a button that I am trying to add and remove a class on and that is working, but as soon as I try and call another function with that new class the function just failed silently. I do not know why this is failing silently and would very much like it to work

Here is a [jsFiddle I'm working with](http://jsfiddle.net/hD7fL/14/), it is extremely stripped down from what I am using it for. So on initial glance it looks like I can do a toggle class, but with all my other code in there it is just not possible.

The same code posted here

```
$('.holdProject').on('click', function(){

    $('.holdProject').addClass('resumeProject');
    $('.holdProject').removeClass('holdProject');
    console.log('here');
});    

$('.resumeProject').on('click', function(){
  $('.resumeProject').addClass('holdProject');
  $('.resumeProject').removeClass('resumeProject');
  console.log('there');
});
```

**Again, this is a very basic example and a toggle class will not be possible for what I am using this for.**

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: What is the question exactly? Can you show us the HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need delegate the click function, since no `.resumeProject` elements exist on DOMReady. You can achieve this by passing in a selector to the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.resumeProject', function() {
    $(this).addClass('resumeProject').removeClass('holdProject');
});
```

In addition, you could easily combine the two handlers using [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.resumeProject,.holdProject', function() { 
    if($(this).is('.resumeProject'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('holdProject').removeClass('resumeProject');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('resumeProject').removeClass('holdProject');
    }
});
```

It is always better of course, to narrow down the delegation, so that the event should be bound to the nearest static parent element. Since we don't know the context or HTML, it's difficult to say for certain what that is in your case.

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/hD7fL/12/)

Comment: With the disclaimer that for performance reasons, you should replace `document` with the nearest static ancestor element.

Comment: Thanks, I was in the process of editing the answer to include the caveat you mention above, @JamesMontagne.

Comment: This works, but could you please put a div where the document is. It's really not a good practice to call the document in an on click.

Comment: You can put a `div` there, but if your button isn't in a `div` then the event won't work. See the caveat I added, it's better to delegate to the closest *static parent*. You only gave us `<button>` in your HTML code, not the whole page so I had to make some assumptions...

Comment: @zazvorniki Can I ask if there's a reason you haven't accepted one of the answers?

Comment: I added a div to my code so that you do not have to call document. In my original code I do have a div and it really is not wise to call anything on document unwise it's document.ready. And I haven't yet accepted an answer because I am a work and people won't stop bugging me while I'm trying to get my code to work.

Comment: Thanks. Trust me, I know the dangers and bad practice of binding everything to `document` ;)

Comment: @BenM It was discussed on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules) that we wouldn't use the `kbd` tags for showcasing demos. Up to you if you want to follow that or not, but I'm in favor.

Comment: Yeah, I did follow that myself, but I personally find it's easier for the OP to spot things inside the `<kbd>` markup than a simple bold text link. If SO permitted a few styling options, maybe I could swayed against it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the binding is set on an element that does not exist. Try scoping the bindings to a parent div or document if you have to like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".holdProject", function(){ 
   $(this).addClass('resumeProject');
   $(this).removeClass('holdProject');
});

$(document).on("click", ".resumeProject", function(){ 
   $(this).addClass('holdProject');
   $(this).removeClass('resumeProject');
});
```

Comment: Binding delegates to document isn't usually a great idea, since it will handle every click event on the entire page before filtering out ones that don't match the criteria.

Comment: I have this running in the document.ready. And Why would I want to attach a click to the document when I have a button with a class?

Comment: the button does not exist at the time the event is declared, you should delegate it to a parent container. I used document because no parent container was specified.

Comment: This does work, but it would be much, much, much better if instead of calling the document you called a div.

Comment: @crush and zazvorniki You are both correct, that is why I suggested to use a parent container, I used document in my code sample for the example's sake, in my answer I specified a parent container is ideal.

Comment: Just think it should be mentioned in your answer is all.

Comment: @crush Yeah I guess, I thought "Try scoping the bindings to a parent div" was enough. My answer does look like it is acceptable to use document.

Comment: It probably is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.holdProject', function(){

    $(this).addClass('resumeProject').removeClass('holdProject');;
    console.log('here');
});    
$(document).on('click', '.resumeProject',function(){
    $(this).addClass('holdProject').removeClass('resumeProject');
    console.log('there');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hD7fL/6/)

Comment: Quick posted, i had not copy your answer, you win @BenM